# How to configure Neo4j embedded driver specified in ogm.properties?

Tags: java, neo4j-ogm, neo4j-embedded

My Java program looks for `ogm.properties` in an application-specific `$DATA_DIR` and loads a `Configuration` that it uses to construct a `SessionFactory`.  The default `ogm.properties` uses the embedded driver and a file URI that points to a subdirectory of `$DATA_DIR`.  So far so good.

The idea is that the user could supply their own `ogm.properties` that uses a different driver.  Therefore, I can't pass a custom `GraphDatabaseService` to the `EmbeddedDriver` constructor because I don't construct it myself.

How can I pass [configuration options](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/) to the embedded driver?  I tried placing a `neo4j.conf` in various locations under `$DATA_DIR`, but it didn't seem to be recognized.

Answer (score 0):

In Neo4j 3.1.6 upcoming by the end of 2018 you'll be able to do the following:

In `ogm.properties`:

```
# Looks in the root of the classpath
neo4j.conf.location=neo4j.conf

# Explicitly in the classpath
# neo4j.conf.location=classpath:neo4j.conf

# Or as file URL
# neo4j.conf.location=file:///config/neo4j.conf
```

Or programmatically in Java configuration:

```
String neo4jConfLocation;

​// Choose one:
​// Looks in the root of the classpath
neo4jConfLocation = "neo4j.conf"

​// Explicitly in the classpath
​// neo4jConfLocation = "classpath:neo4j.conf"

​// Or as file URL
​// neo4jConfLocation = "file:///config/neo4j.conf"

Configuration configuration =
    new Configuration.Builder()
        .neo4jConfLocation(neo4jConfLocation)
        .build();
```

To pass a configuration file from file or classpath resource to the embedded instance.